# API Facebook - FOsUserBundle - Hash password

Tags: php, facebook, api, symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUserBundle and the Facebook API. I want to allow my users to register on my website with this API. Then i want that they can login to my website.

I don't know how i could do the hash of the password, which is auto-generated, to match with FOSUserBundle.

I had found this next code on internet, and i don't understand how i can match this with FOSUserBundle...

If sombebody could help me...Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

```
/**
* Loading and ad-hoc creation of a user by an OAuth sign-in provider account.
*
* @author Fabian Kiss <fabian.kiss@ymc.ch>
*/

class UserProvider extends FOSUBUserProvider{

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
 public function loadUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response){

    try {
        return parent::loadUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
    } catch (UsernameNotFoundException $e) {
        if (null === $user = $this->userManager->findUserByEmail($response->getEmail())) {
            return $this->createUserByOAuthUserResponse($response);
        }

        return $this->updateUserByOAuthUserResponse($user, $response);
    }
 }

 /**
  * {@inheritDoc}
  */
 public function connect(UserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response){
    $providerName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
    $uniqueId = $response->getUsername();
    $user->addOAuthAccount($providerName, $uniqueId);

    $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
 }

 /**
  * Ad-hoc creation of user
  *
  * @param UserResponseInterface $response
  *
  * @return User
  */
 protected function createUserByOAuthUserResponse(UserResponseInterface $response){
    $user = $this->userManager->createUser();

    $this->updateUserByOAuthUserResponse($user, $response);

    // set default values taken from OAuth sign-in provider account
    if (null !== $email = $response->getEmail()) {
        $user->setEmail($email);
    }

    if (null === $this->userManager->findUserByUsername($response->getNickname())) {
        $user->setUsername($response->getNickname());
    }

    $user->setUsername(strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$response->getRealName()).''.rand(0,199)));
    $user->setUsernameCanonical(strtolower(str_replace(' ','',$response->getRealName()).''.rand(0,199)));
    $user->setEnabled(false);

    return $user;
 }

 /**
  * Attach OAuth sign-in provider account to existing user
  *
  * @param FOSUserInterface      $user
  * @param UserResponseInterface $response
  *
  * @return FOSUserInterface
  */
 protected function updateUserByOAuthUserResponse(FOSUserInterface $user, UserResponseInterface $response){
    $providerName = $response->getResourceOwner()->getName();
    $providerNameSetter = 'set'.ucfirst($providerName).'Id';
    $user->$providerNameSetter($response->getUsername());

    if(!$user->getPassword()) {
        // generate unique token
        $secret = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));
        $user->setPassword($secret);
    }

    return $user;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can encode password with encoder_factory and salt of user. 
(I used container to get services, use services into your constructor of  Provider class)

```
    $user = $userManager->createUser();
    $encoder = $this->container->get('security.encoder_factory')->getEncoder($user);  
    $user->setPlainPassword(
    $encoder->encodePassword(
       $this->container->get('fos_user.util.token_generator')->generateToken(),
       $user->getSalt()
       )
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i'm so sorry for the answer a little bit late, but i don't have received any notifications :(i will try your solution :)